# jQuery - Offset of dynamically created element

Tags: jquery, html

**Please have a look at Edit2**
On parts of my website I have the following structure (simplified):

```
<div class="switcher_content">
<!--The Content which should be displayed get's loaded in here by jquery-->
</div>

<div class="cont_1" style="display: none">
Content 1 here
</div>
<div class="cont_2" style="display: none">
Content 2 here
</div>
```

The content displayed on my website is in the `.switcher_content` div. I have a jQuery function that gets the content out of `.cont_1` or `.cont_2`, depending on what the user clicks, and puts it into `.switcher_content` using the `.html` method.

The problem is, when I try to retrieve the offset values of elements that were loaded into the `.switcher_content` div (e.g. `var ot = $(this).offset().top;` - whereas `this` is an element inside `.switcher_content`), I only get `ot = 0`, which is not the case as the element is positioned in the middle of the page.

This all worked fine before I added the possibility to toggle between two contents, so it probably has to do with the fact that the elements were created dynamically.

Is there a way to recalculate the positions and offsets of these elements or how can I retrieve the true offset values of my dynamic elements?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
Here is the code I use for these actions:
This is the switcher:

```
$(".switcher_btn.switcher_to_cont_1").click(function() {
        if($(".sky_go_cntrl").hasClass("active_go")){
            $(".sky_go_cntrl").removeClass("active_go");
            $(".sky_go_cntrl").addClass("active_sln");

            var newhtml = $(".cont_1").html();
            $(".switcher_content").html(newhtml);
        }

    })
```

It's basically just getting the html out of.cont_1 and using it as content of the .switcher_content.

Then I'm trying to get the offset values with this code:

```
$(".all_planes a").css({fontSize: "16px"})
$( ".plane_container" ).each(function( ) {
    var st = $(window).scrollTop() + 98;
    var ot = $(this).offset().top;
    var type = $(this).data("type");
    var diff = st - ot;
    if(st > ot && diff < 280) {
        if (window.console) console.log(this);

        $("." + type + "_link").css({
            fontSize: "20px"
        });
    }
});
```

And looking at the console, I do seem to select the div boxes I want.

**Edit2**
I may have identified the real problem as everything is working fine in my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1Lret7vk/3/). By looking at my `st` and `ot` variable values I have found out that adding 98 to `st` suddenly completly changes the `ot` value while scrolling which should be constant. If I remove the 98, then `ot` doesn't change when scrolling. So there somehow seems to be a different problem.

Comment: print to console your 'this' - to make sure it knows what selector 'this' is - that should clue you in if it's targeting the right element.

Comment: Please share the code that is used for the actions mentioned.

Comment: I checked the console and I'm targeting the right elements. I've also added the jQuery code. Thanks!

Comment: Can you share a http://jsfiddle.net/ with your  code?

Comment: I just found out that a stripped down version of my code seems to be working ([link](https://jsfiddle.net/1Lret7vk/3/)) and then started experimenting with my original code again. It seems to be the 98 I add to the `st` variable. Without it my code works as it should but I need to add the value to take a fixed header into account.